# Android show webview content from device internal memory

Tags: android, webview, kotlin, android-webview

I have a folder that is saved to device internal memory and I want to display `html` content (with images, `.css` styles and other things that we found on regular websites but **not using any internet connection**). So all the necessary resources exist in that folder (images in img folder styles in css folder and so on...) Here's how the content of folder looks like
 [image]

and here how I load data to `webview`

```
fun showWebsite(fileName: String) {
        post { loadDataWithBaseURL(path, reader.readFileContext(fileName), "text/html", "UTF-8", null) }
    }
```

Here how I get `path`

```
 private val ref = WeakReference(context)
        var path: String? = null

        init {
            path = ref.get()?.filesDir?.absolutePath + File.separator
        }
```

Here's path value `/data/user/0/com.web.webdemo/files/`

I load data to webview using `loadDataWithBaseURL` method and I pass the path to web folder in internal storage. The thing is that I can see the content of specific `html` file except for images and styles. So why is that? What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT1**

here's my html content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/lib.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">

</head>


<body>

  Hello Start
  <img src="img/test.png" alt="super image">


  <button onclick="next()">Press me</button>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT2**

OK, so I solved one part of problem. Now my `css` styles are loaded. I added **"file://"** to `baseUrl` Full code

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("file://" + reader.path, reader.readFileContext(fileName), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
```

But images is still missing :/

Comment: That looks like a folder on your development machine. Unreachable for an Android app on an Android device far away from home. Which language/ide are you programming in?

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for the comment I'm using Android Studio with Kotlin

Comment: Please post all code as text. You make it impossible for us to copy paste something.

Comment: Seems a matter with the paths you're using on your html. Certify youself they are this way '<img src="img/test.png">' css/... and js/...

Comment: @greenapps I updated my question, please take a look

Comment: @statosdotcom my paths are correct, please take a look at my updated question

Comment: What is the value of fileName? And what does that reader.readFileContext(fileName)?

Comment: @greenapps the value of `file.readFIleContext(fileName)` is html content that posted in my question

Comment: ??? I would expect you were loading a html file from your files directory using the path variable. Then what is in that html file? Please give complete code as you let us guess what you are doing. And you did not tell the value of fileName.

Comment: You should just use loadUrl() instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172472/discussion-between-david-and-greenapps).

Comment: Hi i want to display an html file available on my device in internal storage on a webview. Did you manage to do it ? And how did you manager to see internal memory as file in your first image?

Comment: Note that for API 30 you will need to set webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); to access internal files from WebView